# Vim tabs with screen?

Tags: display, vim

When I use tabs in vim, I use the shortcut ctrl+pgup and ctrl+pgdn for navigating between tabs. I realize I can do :tabnext and :tabprev, but that is certainly more keystrokes.

Everything works fine until I'm running vim in a screen session. To reproduce:

```
touch .screenrc.tmp && screen -c .screenrc.tmp
```

(launch screen with an empty screenrc)

then run:

```
vim -p file1 file2
```

and attempt to navigate between tabs via ctrl+pgup and ctrl+pgdn. Some strange capitalization changes will happen too, if you have some text in either file.

screen version is 4.00.03jw4

vim version is 7.3.429

Thanks!

Comment: The normal way to do this is `gt` and `gT`. Move forward or backwards a tab. Most likely pageup and pagedown are being interpreted differently in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `t_kP` option in each scenario.  Vim in Xterm is `^[[5;*~`; Vim in Screen is `^[[5~`.  When the latter value is used for that option, the escape sequence `^[[5;5~` isn't recognized as being ctrl-pageup.  I always use xterm, so this plugin will set `t_kP` and other Vim terminal options so modified F keys, page up/down, etc. just work: https://github.com/godlygeek/vim-files/blob/master/plugin/terminalkeys.vim